# Is it OK to modify the default location for Python-3.6.0.exe to just the C drive?

Tags: python-3.x, download

I am a 65 year old "newbie" and generally use default options when downloading.  **Python.org** wants to download to an obscure directory such as

> C:\Users\Facdev\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32".

Is there anything wrong with downloading instead to "C:"?

Answer (score 0):

This should not pose a problem, as long as the directory is specified correctly in you `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to modify the location where you will download and install Python. However, I would advise against doing so if you are unfamiliar with how system environment variables and `PATH` locations work in Windows.

**Why does it matter?**

Once you have the python executable (in your case `Python-3.6.0.exe`) on your system, your computer needs to know where it is in order to execute it! If you place the executable in a location like the main directory on the C: drive your computer does not care. Your computer also does not care if the executable is deep down in the AppData\ directory.

By changing the default behavior you run a risk when troubleshooting unexpected behavior that instructions will not be written for your situation. This is OK as long as you understand what you will need to change in order to apply the troubleshooting techniques listed on documentation, blog posts, and forums.

Because of those factors and this being a new process for you, I recommend sticking to the default. You can change the location later, once you understand what doing so means. Learning to program can be frustrating and trying to grasp managing the software environment only adds to the frustration. Tackle that issue later.

Good luck on your new adventure! I hope you learn to enjoy writing your own programs in python!